# Structuring React Components with API calls, user inputs, etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble implementing what I want in React.

I've found some examples and gone through part 1 of the Codecademy React tutorial. So, I understand props and state on some level, but I'm finding it hard to apply to my specific use case.

I have a Python Flask API that I'd like to make calls to. I'm going to use basic `XMLHttpRequest`s like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        callback(xhr.responseText)
        }

param1 = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("param1").value);
param2 = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("param2").value);
xhr.open("GET", "/apicall?param1="+param1+"&param2="+param2", true);
xhr.send(null);
```

My Flask API can handle this and perform some calculations based on the parameters and return a JSON object with the results i.e.:

```
{
 result1: 100,
 result2: 150
}
```

My basic page structure right now is an input section and a results section.
The input section has two buttons at the bottom. Button 1 is to calculate and display the results (should make the API call and cause the results section to become visible if the input data is valid and the API call returns a valid result). Button 2 is to clear (should clear and hide the results section, and clear the input values from their boxes in the input section).

The results section also has a button at the bottom, to display additional results that will require another API call (using parameters from both the input section and the results section).

This project started out using html templates manipulated with jQuery, so as of now, my React components aren't doing anything "React-y" yet (which is sort of the main thing I'm having trouble with).

Here's some example code of what I have right now:

```
var Input = React.createClass({

    render () {

        return (
            <div className="input-container">
              <h2>Inputs</h2>
              <h4>Input 1</h4>
              <input className="input-box" name="param1" id="param1"/>
              <input className="input-box" name="param2" id="param2"/>
              <button className="input-btn" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
              <button className="input-btn" id="clear">Clear</button>
            </div>
            );
        }
    });
```

What I'm thinking is I need to set the button's onClick prop to the API calling function, which I guess should be a method inside the Input class?

My Results section is something like this:

```
var Results = React.createClass({

    render () {

    return (
        <div className="results-container" style={display: 'none'}>
          <h2>Results</h2>
          <p>Result 1 is <strong><span id="result1"></span></strong></p>
          <p>Result 2 is <strong><span id="result2"></span></strong></p>
          <button class="btn" id="show-result-plots">Show Results Plots</button>
          <div className="plots-container">
            <div id="plot1"></div>
            <div id="plot2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
});
```

So, obviously I need to pass the API data that I'm gonna get from the Input component to the Result component, presumably using props. But it seems like the Result component needs to be a child of the Input component, or they both need a parent that is passing data between them. Less importantly, I also need to update the state of the Result component to become visible when the API call is successful.

I've got most of the pieces but I'm struggling to put them together in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look into using [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) for your data handling. This will simply the flow of everything in your app. If you don't want to use that to handle state and actions then I believe you are on the right path.

There should be a parent component that has Input and Results as children. The parent component should contain the data fetching functions and pass them as props to the children. The data that the api calls returns should also be passed as props to the child that requires the data. Children components should be "dumb", essentially displaying data. The parent component should handle everything else.

Comment: Thanks, I think it may be a good idea to look into Redux because eventually this is gonna be a very data heavy app.

Comment: @chiiidog If that's the case then it is way better to try to understand and implement it early on. Might take you a little to wrap your head around, but once you do it will make your life so much easier in the end. Having a central place to manage state and being able to split up your actions is a huge help.